# Using BoxLayout without container target?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I'm trying to use BoxLayout instead of my GridLayout code:

```
setLayout (new GridLayout (5, 2));
```

except I noticed that when you do BoxLayout you need to do something like:

```
setLayout (new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

However, I don't call the JFrame something, like how it would be called:

```
JFrame label = new JFrame ();
```

it basically just works in the constructor.. I'm obviously a beginner in Java but do have some understanding. Because I don't call the JFrame and simply write:

```
add (controlPanel);
add (outputPanel);
```

What do I put into the target part of the BoxLayout? I do want it to be on the Y axis but I'm not sure what to put in the field before it instead of the "container" thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use  [JFrame's content pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane%28%29) as target.

```
setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! I actually tried that but without the () so I didn't bother to include it in my question. Thanks!

Comment: It's a method that is present in `JFrame`. Look at the shared link. you can call it ins this ways as well `this.getContentPane()`.

Comment: @user3566347: if this answer solved your problem, then you will want to both up-vote it and accept it by clicking on the large check-mark next to it.